# Organizing my data under the metadata navigation term store

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, managed-metadata, sharepoint-server, term-store

I am working on a Wiki library for our company. The idea of the wiki is to organize our work per department, then per project. For example for our financial dept we will have the following hierarchy:-

> > Annual bank settlement
> >
> > > Bank A
> > >
> > > > 2013
> > > >         2012
> > >
> > > BankB
> >
> > Salaries

For our Software engineering

> > ProjectA
> >
> > Requirement
> >
> > Design
> >
> > ProjectB
> >
> > Requirement
> >
> > Design
> >
> > ProjectC

Now the problem with organizing our information in this way, it will create conflicts. For example under each project inside the SW engineering dept. there is a “Design” term, so when the user click on the Design link it will take him to different Wiki articles for specific project, while the logic would say that clicking on the “Design” should show all the wikis that are tagged as Design regardless of the project there are under it. How can I organize my term store to be more useful and remove any conflicts?

[image]